# How To Set A Range That Has An Unknown Starting Index

Tags: python

I am wondering how I can define a function that allows the range to be set to whatever the starting index is for a certain list. For example:

```
def pTrend(stock):
    pTrend = []
    for x in range(0, len(stock)):
         if x > 0:
              print('This')
         if x < 0:
              print('That')
```

I have lists of stock data, and the first one is from range(0, 250) and the next is from (250, 500) and etc.. how could i create a function that sets the start at the range = to the particular index of each stock i will be plugging in?

Comment: Why not just iterate of the stock data without indexing, e.g. `for x in stock:`? I'm not sure what you believe `x` is in your example it will always be `> 0`

Comment: Would enumerate work for you? Like: '''for c in enumerate(stock)'''

Comment: Do you have a separate sequence of stock *names* that is in the same order as the list of data?

Comment: @OP, was your question answered? If not, you could ask for clarification in comments. Otherwise, please mark the answer as accepted, if it helped.

Comment: Yes thank you very much this helped immensely

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider it good form to have functions maintain state like this. If possible, you should try and have the caller code maintain the state for you. For example, have the caller code maintain a `cumsum` variable that you pass to `pTrend` as the offset.

```
def pTrend(stock, offset):
    pTrend = []
    for i in range(len(stock)):
        i += offset
        ...
```

This is in effect, what `enumerate` (as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205997/how-to-set-a-range-that-has-an-unknown-starting-index/50206027#comment87429168_50205997)) does:

```
def pTrend(stock, offset):
    for i, s in enumerate(stock, offset):
        ...
```

Now, in your caller code, you have:

```
cumsum = 0
for stock in stocks:
    ... = pTrend(stock, cumsum)
    cumsum += len(stock)
```

---

Alternatively, define a class and have it keep track of the `cumsum` variable for you.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cumsum = 0

    def pTrend(self, stock): 
        pTrend = []
        for i, s in enumerate(stock, self.cumsum):
            ...
        self.cumsum += len(stock)
```

Initialise an object:

```
f = Foo()
```

And call `pTrend` as `f.pTrend(stock)` as you would usually.